# Where to find connected VS Code apps in setup

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, connected-apps, vs-code, setup

I tried finding the connected VS Code apps in `Connected Apps OAuth Usage` and `Manage Connected Apps` but could not find it. I have below queries:

1. Where to find which all VS Code apps (and which systems) are accessing my org
2. Is it possible to disconnect/logout VS Code from my org? (I no longer have access to a system which I used for some time)
3. What is the exact difference between `Connected Apps OAuth Usage` and `Manage Connected Apps`

**Connected Apps OAuth Usage**

[image]

**Manage Connected Apps**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Behind the scenes VS Code (running CLI commands) uses an Out of the Box "[Global Connected App](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_auth.htm)". This is provided by Salesforce and you don't need to configure anything around it. So it's not exactly the VS Code that is connected, but the User who was authorized for that Org, connected using this app. So to answer your questions:

1. You will find this app in Setup --> Connected Apps OAuth Usage section.
2. Yes. You can revoke the access from the page mentioned above. It lists down the count of Users connected, and upon clicking that you will be able to revoke the access
3. [Connected Apps Usage](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?err=1&id=connected_app_monitor.htm&type=5) helps you to manage OAuth settings for a specific app. [Manage Connected Apps](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=connected_app_manage.htm&type=0) lists down all installed apps and lets you manage a specific apps policies.